# Deploying Node.js typescript application to heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

I'm stuck deploying a Node.js typescript application to Heroku. It would be great if you could help me out.

If I run `npm run build`, `npm run start` or `npm run start:dev` everything seems to work just fine. When I try to deploy my app to Heroku using `git push heroku main` I get the following error:

[image: Heroku deployment error]

I checked every import in my application, but couldn't find a single one being incorrect or missing in `"dependencies"` in my `package.json`.

I am truely clueless about the solution, but I figured some extra information might be useful:

file structure:

[image: file structure]

procfile:

```
web: node build/server.js
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                     
    "module": "commonjs",                  
    "lib": ["es6"],                     
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",                          
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,         
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run build && node build/server.js",
    "start:dev": "set NODE_ENV=development&& npm run build && nodemon --ext \".ts,.js\" --watch \"./src\" --exec \"ts-node ./src/server.ts\"",
    "start:local": "set NODE_ENV=local&& nodemon",
    "test": "ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json ./src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "coverage": "nyc -r lcov -e .ts -x \"*.test.ts\" npm run test",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc"
  }
```

Comment: That screenshot doesn't show any of the modules from the error message. But looking in the repo I note it's e.g. [`Interface`](https://github.com/tpmulder/chess-app-api/blob/main/src/app/models/challenge/Interface.ts) not `interface`. It looks like you're using Windows locally; the Heroku dyno is Linux, you'll have to take care with your casing.

Comment: Oh, yes I will update the screenshot. I used PascalCase for file names. I'll try to deploy the app again when I checked all my imports on casing as well. If that runs without any errors I'll upvote your comment :) Ty in advance!

Comment: Seems like github didn't change the filenames. While I had the right filenames locally, in github they were all wrong, so I had to remove the projects gitfile, change the filenames and forcepush after initted a new git file. Thanks again for helping me out @jonrsharpe. If someone else reads this: Pay attention to namecasing -> local filenames must match the github filenames

Answer (score 0):

Seems like github didn't change my filenames. While I had the right filenames locally, in github they were all wrongly cased. I had to remove the projects gitfile, change the filenames and forcepush to my git repo after I initialized a new git file in my project. Thanks to @jonrsharpe I noticed how important casing can be and how we should watch carefully if everything is written the way it should be. If someone else came across the same issue: Pay attention to namecasing -> local filenames must match the github filenames !!